# how to generate seo friedly url using long url parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url

https://www.website.com/result.php?class_id=4&subject_id=22&city=6&locality_id=67&tutor_type=1

I want to get all the parameter of this url and try to show the result. and i am success on that. My problem is that, i just want to change this url to seo friendly url with text only like this

https://www.website.com/class-1/math/new-jersy/block1/online-tutors

In this seo friendly url, but i want to get all the parameter values of first url through this url. i tried the htaccess but not success. looking for your help. thanks.

I tried this htaccess, not success

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\[^/\]\*)/$ /result.php?class_id=4&subject_id=22&city=6&locality_id=67&tutor_type=1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do clarify about parameters in your URL which you are hitting in browser are different from URL you want to change in browser? Kindly do elaborate more on same, thank you.

Comment: Unless you want to rewrite just this one specific URL (which I doubt) then you can't do this in `.htaccess` as written since _none_ of the information in the target URL is present in the URL being requested. For instance, where are you expecting to get the `4` from in `class_id=4` and the `22` in `subject_id=22`, etc. when you are requesting `/class-1/math/new-jersy/block1/online-tutors`?